# Can I have a foreign key reference a composite primary key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a tableA that has two fk as composite pk. I have another table that wants to reference tableA. Preferably reference it has one key to the composite key.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key should also be composite, and reference the composite primary key of tableA with both columns, in the same order.

The idea you should keep in mind is that a foreign key should reference exactly one row in the referenced table. If it references only one column of a composite primary key, then there can be multiple rows with the same value in that column. To be guaranteed to reference only one row, the foreign key must match all column(s) of the primary key.

Comment: Example fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/TqLyhUcm